# How to add all rows and subtract one particular row in table and insert in to new table?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have gone through a crazy problem .iam doing manually in XL sheet is there any chance of doing in stored proc.

I created a stored proc for insering data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dataloading
AS
BEGIN
    truncate table TABLE1

    insert TABLE1 (
        [Name],
        [Share]
    )
    select 
        [Name], 
        sum(Share)
    from TABLE2
    group by [Share]

END


Output is 

texas     3000 

dallas    5000

ca        5000

sfo       7000

newyork   8000

alaska    4000
```

I need to the ouput enter in to TABLE1 as adding all share except alaska and subtracting alska  and print in the below row .

```
I want output look like :-
texas     3000 

dallas    5000

ca        5000

sfo       7000

newyork   8000

G total  28000

alaska    4000

Total    24000
```

Can you one look in to this please??

Answer (score 1):

you could try consecutive inserts:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Dataloading
AS
BEGIN
truncate table TABLE1

insert TABLE1 (
    [Name],
    [Share]
)
select 
    [Name], 
    sum(Share)
from TABLE2
 where [Name] not like '%alaska%'
group by [Share]

insert TABLE1 (
    [Name],
    [Share]
)
select 'G total', sum([Share]) from TABLE1 

insert TABLE1 (
    [Name],
    [Share]
)
select 
    [Name], 
    sum(Share)
from TABLE2
 where [Name] like '%alaska%'
group by [Share]

insert TABLE1 (
    [Name],
    [Share]
)
select 'Total', sum([Share]) from TABLE1 

END
```

hope it helps a bit :)

you may also add some creazy sorting colum. Probably you will need it

Comment: maybe, I haven't tested it